# Could the SSMEs of the SLS do retro burns?

Tags: reuse, sls, vertical-landing

The SLS will use the main engines of the space shuttle. Are these capable of retro-burns in the upper atmosphere like SpaceX’s Merlin engines?

More broadly, could the SLS’ main engines and supporting thrusters perform a vertical landing if programmed with proper software?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They cannot, because SSMEs cannot be restarted in flight. See this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34418/6944) for the details as to why.

Comment: Wow. That’s a bummer. This thing really is the Senate Launch System.

Comment: IMHO it's criminal to dump those SSMEs into the ocean.